EF Core 7 vs SQL query
I want to execute a select using a specific type but I get an error.
SELECT * FROM TABLE(MY_CUSTOM_FU(:my_param))


System.InvalidOperationException: 'The element type 'MyCustomRow' used in 'SqlQuery' method is not natively supported by your database provider. Either use a supported element type, or use ModelConfigurationBuilder.DefaultTypeMapping to define a mapping for your type.'

I tried to execute a select statement with a custom object.
It works in EF 6 using the SqlQuery:
rows = Database.SqlQueryRaw<MyCustomRow>("SELECT * FROM TABLE(MY_CUSTOM_FU(:my_param))", myParam);


Can you provide a bit more clarity of what you looking for? What is the actual question?
Is the function you defined, a database function? What does the function return?

Does this answer your question? Error in 'SqlQuery' method is not natively supported by your database provider
